# Explanation of a simple algorithm's Big O complexity

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I'm looking at a past paper, where there is the following Algorithm, and we are asked to give the runtime in O notation:

```
Loop2(n)
    for i := 0 to n
        j := 0
        s := 0
        while s <= i
            j := j + 1
            s := s + j
```

I can see that the outer loop (alone) is run $O(n)$ times, and that the inner loop is $O(\sqrt n)$. However, the part that confuses me is that the correct answer, according to the paper, is $O(n \cdot \sqrt n)$.

I though that, since the inner loop is dependent on $i$, that it would be run $\sqrt i$ times, for $i$ going from $0..n$. Meaning that in total, the loop would run roughly $n$ times, making the whole algorithm $O(n\cdot n)=O(n^2)$. I kinda drew the logic from an analysis of insertion sort, where $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} n-i = O(n^2)$$

I think I remember the above correctly. Can anyone fix my broken logic here?

Comment: You need more structure in your analysis; see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). There are also some examples available: [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop is $O(\sqrt{i})$, you are correct. Since $i\leq n$, then $\sqrt{i}\leq \sqrt{n}$, and we have
$n\times\sqrt{i}\leq n\times\sqrt{n}$. Hence the complexity is  $O(n\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The inner loop is $O(\sqrt i)$, but since the loop is executed $n$ times, then the inner loop is essentially $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt i$. Is this just $O(\sqrt n)$? Why?

Comment: It's a `while` inside a `for`.  For each $i$, the `while` takes $O(\sqrt{i})$. There are $n$ `for`-iterations, so $O(n\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Ah it suddenly clicked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Using Landau terms in nested fashion is prone to producing errors. It's better to be more explicit about the cost.